# Is the following function bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, bounded-variation

I have function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^m}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-a_i^x)^{n_i},~~x>0$$
where $0<a_i<1, n_i\geq0$ and ${m=\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_i}.$ Is it bounded?
It can be shown that $\displaystyle{lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)}=0.$ Also, $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$. If we can calculate 
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+} }f(x)$, we can respond to this question. Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: Note that as $m=\sum n_i$, you fonction is the product of the $(\frac{1-a_i^x}{x})^{n_i}$. So you have only to study if, for $0<a<1$, $\frac{1-a^x}{x}$ has a limit.

Comment: $$lim_{x\to 0}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(\frac{1-a_i^x}{x})^{n_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-log (a_i))^{n_i}<\infty$$